# How can we achieve tis result in mysql?

Tags: mysql

ID  Student  Classes

1   Mark     Maths,Science,English

2   John     Science,English

3   Robert   Maths,English

output:

```
ID  Student    Value

1   Mark       Maths
1   Mark       Science
1   Mark       English
2   John       Science
2   John       English
3   Robert     Maths
3   Robert     English
```

Comment: Kindly post your efforts/code/output  then only we can help you, also kindly refer to this [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have 3 tables in your database "student", "subject"(Classes) and "student_subject" or similar, then

```
SELECT
student.id,
student.`name`,

GROUP_CONCAT(`subject`.`subject`) as Classes

FROM
student
LEFT JOIN student_subject ON student.id = student_subject.id_student
RIGHT JOIN `subject` ON `subject`.id = student_subject.id_subject
GROUP BY student.id;
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: I have one table named  "StudentClasses"  in that ID,Student,Classes these are columns.

Comment: You only have 1 table?  Your table is like this                                                       ID  Student    Value
1   Mark       Maths                                                                                                    Or                                                                                                                          ID  Student    Value
1   Mark       Maths,Science,English   ... You need to explain better your situation.